# How to get selected language from Electron-builder NSIS

Tags: javascript, electron, nsis, electron-builder

Can I access the selected language during installation of NSIS on my Electron app?

packaged using Electron-builder

Reference: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5352

I'd like to access the selected language to set my app's default language.

And would like the same for PKG target on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the selected language in NSIS is stored in the **$LANGUAGE** variable.

Use it for your Electron app - e.g. pass the language as parameter or write it to your configuration, etc. (this depends on your app).